# Views - No results behavior with Exposed filter criteria

Tags: views

I have a views setup with one title field, exposed filter criteria and No results behavior (Simple Text). Problem is No results behavior shows before user applied any filter criteria. I need No results behavior to show up only if filter criteria didn't find any content. Help please and thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I think you selected the **Autosubmit** option in the exposed form settings.

> > Autosubmit
> >     Automatically submit the form once an element is changed